# How to use same Future another .dart file? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, future

I'd like to use Future `teamMember()` in another `.dart` file. Any contributions are welcome!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Popups(),
    ));
}


class Popups extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PopupsState createState() => _PopupsState();
}

class _PopupsState extends State<Popups> {

Future teamMember() async {
   await showDialog(
       context: context,
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the other class where you need it create a reference     to your popup class and then call teamMember.

```
   class OtherClass extends StatelessWidget {
    Popups _popups = Popups();

    .
    .
       RaisedButton(
         child: Text("show team member popup"),
         onPressed: (){
            _popups.teamMember();
         }
       )
    }
```

hope this helps